# Adding new row in tapply function dataframe

Tags: r, function, rbind

I have function which calculates the count based on my condition. And I need to get total counts for each column at the end of my table. these were codes I tried,

```
t1<- doCounts1(AE_subset$Disp_code,AE_subset$FY, "Count of Attendances")

doCounts1<- function(var1,var2,varname,fun=NULL) {

  if (is.null(fun)) {
    a1<- as.data.frame.matrix(table(var1,var2))
  } else {
    a1<- as.data.frame.matrix(tapply(testvar,list(var1,var2),FUN=fun,na.rm=TRUE))
  }

  a1<- rownames_to_column(a1,var=varname)

  a1$FY3PR<- a1$FY3*proRata

  if (!is.null(fun))
    if (fun=="mean")
      a1$FY3PR<- a1$FY3

  **a1<- a1 %>% replace(., is.na(.), 0)
  a1<- rbind(a1,c("Total",as.numeric(colSums(a1[,2:4]))))**


  return(a1)
}
```

My output table is like Var1 FY1,FY2,FY3,FY3PR.
My expected output like,
Var1   FY1  FY2  FY3 FY3PR
1      20   30   40  80
2      40   50   10  20
**Total  60   80   50  100**
So, here everything works fine except my rbind code (Marked in bold). I replaced all NA <- 0 then calculated my total counts. Total column counts.
Its not working in my function.
ANybody have idea to achieve this?

Comment: @ Zheyuan Li - Yes, that's the issue here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sample` function is used to generate random numbers.

You can specify exactly what values you want to feature in your random ordering by leaving the `replace` argument as `FALSE`.

First create all the values you want to feature, repeated as many times as you want them.

```
vals <- rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 4L)
```

Then sample your selection without replacing:

```
rsample <- sample(vals, 12L, replace = FALSE)
```

Comment: Just `sample(vals)` is enough in this case.

Comment: Indeed, but nice to see how the options work.  Key to the question is `replace = FALSE` so I have put that explicitly even though that's the default.